# Find the right statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likert

currently I'm trying to test some hypothesis, but I'm a little bit puzzled on choosing an appropriate test method. So, my data consists of two observations - First: Ordinal data from Likert-scale, Second: Continuous data (e.g., times in seconds). Since, I don't want to compare ordinal vs. ordinal or continuous vs. continuous data, all the cheat sheets etc. don't give me an answer or I'm just too blind to find it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What's your hypothesis?  You can't test "some hypothesis" without specifying one.  Perhaps you could test if the mean of the continuous data is the same across different ordinal values. In that framework, and with assumptions as to the distribution of the continuous data, you could compare the sample means for distinct subsets defined by the ordinal data.  If the sample means are too distant (as measured by sample variance), you would reject "H0: the continuous means are the same for all ordinal values."

Comment: Sorry missed that: my hypothesis is, that there is a correlation between an increased Likert scale score and the continuous data.

Comment: The way tests are usually set up is as a straw man.  If you want to end up entertaining the idea that there is correlation, you would test that the correlation is zero.  If you can knock that hypothesis down, you would move on and estimate the correlation in a more complex model (more complex than no correlation).

Comment: Thanks for our reply. Given your approach to measure the mean for every Likert-scale value, you should mean - I should perform a Spearman correlation test for every Likert scale value. To get the relation between eg., value = 1 and necessary times within the sample, right?

Comment: Please add extra info in comments to the post as an edit. We want posts to be self-contained, few people read comments, and comments can be deleted